# Where can I find the Visual Studio 2010 Command Prompt executable?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, command-prompt

I lost the tools menu of my Visual Studio 2010.

Where can I find the VS 2010 command prompt executable - what is the name of the file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shortcut for **Visual Studio Command Prompt (2010)** has:

`Target: %comspec% /k ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"" x86`

`Start in: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\"`

`%comspec%` expands to an instruction to the shell to find the command-line shell, wherever it is.

Comment: when I doulb click "vcvarsall.bat" file nothing happens unfortunately :(

Comment: @pencilCake create a shortcut with the above properties and try that

Answer (score 1):

Check for it in the start menu

Answer (score 0):

The executable is just CMD.exe (c:\windows\system32, for example). The environment is set up by batch files.

A quick way to get to the batch files (for VS 2012) is go to `%VS110COMNTOOLS%` and look for the different `.bat` files.

For other VS versions change the VS110, so for 2010 use `%VS100COMNTOOLS`.